# How to view NSLog outside of Xcode console

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I see there is a way to view NSLog output in Xcode console, but I don't run my apps from Xcode. I install them to a simulator and black box test the apps with Appium automated testing client. How can I see the output form the apps while they are being testing with the Appium client? I've looked at the system.log but don't see the NSLog output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MacOS built-in `console.app`. Here is how it looks on my machine:

[image: "iPhone 8" is a simulator]

In my case "iPhone 8" is a simulator